# drop down should appear only on certain rows of listview wpf MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm

My styles and resources

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ConvertorObj:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVis"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="GridBlockStyle">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Visibility"  
        Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,      
        AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},
        Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}, ConverterParameter=False}" />
        <Setter Property ="FontFamily" Value="Verdana" ></Setter>
        <Setter Property ="FontSize" Value="14" ></Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" x:Key="GridEditStyle">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Visibility"  
                Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},
                Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}, ConverterParameter=True}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger>

            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

These are the two types of styles applied, GridBlockStyle and GridEditStyle. In a normal view the rows should behave like textblocks. When I edit the row it should behave as textbox with a combobox. The problem is that I get comboboxes in all the rows of the listview. it should appear only in certain rows of my listview.

My listview is as follows

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="ListValues" AlternationCount="2"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path= ListValues}" 
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >

               <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00B2EE">
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
               </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                   <ListView.View>
                       <GridView>
                           <GridViewColumn Width="200">
                               <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Name" Content="Name" />
                                   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                       <DataTemplate>
                                           <Grid>
                                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Style="{StaticResource GridBlockStyle}" />
                                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}" />
                                           </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>

                                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Settings" Content="Settings" />
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="240"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                                                           Style="{StaticResource GridBlockStyle}" 
                                                           Text="{Binding Path=Settings}"/>
                                                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" 
                                                         Text="{Binding Path=Settings}" 
                                                         FontFamily="verdana" FontSize="14" 
                                                         MaxLength="31" Width="240" 
                                                         Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Style="`{StaticResource GridBlockStyle}" />`
                                                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
                                                          Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}"
                                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CmbSettings}"
                                                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CmbSelectType}"
                                                          IsEnabled="{Binding Path = IsComboAvailable}"  
                                                          Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>

                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

Sample view model

```
        _sampleModel = new SampleModel();
        _sampleModel.Name = "test1";
        _sampleModel.Settings = "aa";
        _sampleModel.IsComboAvailable = false;

        ListValues.Add(_sampleModel);

        _sampleModel = new SampleModel();
        _sampleModel.Name = "test1";
        _sampleModel.Settings = "3";
        _sampleModel.CmbSelectType = "Second";
        _sampleModel.CmbSettings.Add("Second");
        _sampleModel.CmbSettings.Add("Minute");

        _sampleModel.IsComboAvailable = true;
        ListValues.Add(_sampleModel);
        ListValues.Add(_sampleModel);
```

Currently on editing the row the disabled dropdown is visible. It should be removed.

[image: Example picture below:]

Answer (score 0):

When IsEnabled is false, a ComboBox will appear grayed out and not be editable. However, since you have located the TextBlock and the ComboxBox in the same grid column, and the ComboBox is declared later, your TextBlock is still covered by the ComboBox even when the ComboBox is disabled. What you want to do is set the Visibility to Collapsed when IsComboAvailable is false.

Try this:

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Name="combo" 
    ...
</Grid>
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsComboAvailable}" Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="combo" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```